CodeIgniter 4 Shield session cookie expiration not being updated
I'm using CI4 with Shield. I want the session to stay active indefinitely. In Config\Session.php I set the "expiration" and "timeToUpdate" properties to 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 (I also tried setting to 0). However, the cookie "ci_session" that gets created has an expiration of the same day still. How do I actually change that?
Action: Set Config\Session->expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
Expectation: I expected the ci_session cookie to be created with an expiration date of next year.
Result: ci_session cookie is created with same day expiration still.
